# How to make editable Recordsource from two sources

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am not too sure about the wording of my title but I hope I can describe the problem here well enough. Also I have made two previous posts. In [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866149/how-do-you-fill-a-recordsource-with-values-from-an-ado-recordset) I describe another problem with my approach that has been solved. In the post there is a link to the question prior to it. That might help understand my problem and I don't need to repeat everything.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvcWp.jpg) is the current state of the form I am looking at. In the code below you can see how I fill the table. The default values for the checkbox and the "Zieladresse" fields are *No* and *Null*.

```vb
Dim cpRS As New ADODB.Recordset, rs As DAO.Recordset, otherRS As DAO.Recordset, cb As checkBox, addr As String
'Creating copy of previously displayed result table
Set cpRS = New ADODB.Recordset
With cpRS
    .Fields.Append "val1", adInteger
    .Fields.Append "val2", adInteger
    '...
    'new Fields for editable purpose
    '########################################
    .Fields.Append "auswahl", adBoolean
    .Fields.Append "Zieladresse", adVarChar, 50, adFldIsNullable

    .CursorLocation = adOpenKeyset
    .Open , , adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, 8
End With

'Dim argv() As String
'Dim argRest As String - not used in this excerpt
Dim qdef As DAO.QueryDef
Dim restrictedQuery As String
Dim i As Long

restrictedQuery = "some SQL"

Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("")
qdef.SQL = restrictedQuery
Set rs = qdef.OpenRecordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(restrictedQuery, dbOpenSnapshot)
rs.MoveLast
rs.MoveFirst
If rs.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "error", vbOKOnly, "error"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name
    Exit Sub
End If

'populate new recordset with data from table in previous form
Do Until rs.EOF
    cpRS.AddNew
    cpRS.Fields("val1") = rs("val1")
    '...
    cpRS.Update
    rs.MoveNext
Loop

Set otherRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("tbl_Auswahl")
otherRS.MoveFirst

Do Until cpRS.EOF
    cpRS.Fields("auswahl") = otherRS("auswahl")
    cpRS.Fields("Zieladresse") = otherRS("Zieladresse")
    cpRS.Update
    cpRS.MoveNext
Loop
```

In the vba I open the Recordset and first fill it with values from the query which is a group by query (and therefore read-only). Then I open another Recordset (otherRS) and fill the other two columns with the values from a table (so not read-only). As you can see in the screenshot that doesn't really work. So my question is: How do I get the default values to be shown for every checkbox and every textfield (the address) and make them editable, so a user can open this Form and check boxes and enter values for the address column? It would not matter if the user could also edit the other columns because they will not be used.

Comment: If Zieladresse field should be null, why does it show ***#Name?*** error? When I use temp table, I create permanent table then INSERT/DELETE records with SQL actions - no QueryDef code.

Comment: @June7 I've had this problem, too, with the other columns as mentioned in the linked previous question. I can only guess though, why I get this error. Prior to this, the problem was that the field name did not match the name of the table I used to populate the Recordset with but this time that is not the source of my problem. Also I should clarify that I don't create the table and dispose at the end of my use with it. So it is, in fact, a permanent table with temporary records- just like you described. I will edit my question. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: You say you want two fields to show 'default values' then code attempts to populate those fields with values from a table. Code as is would set every record in cpRS to values from first record of otherRS. An UPDATE sql could populate table fields without looping a recordset. Show samples of source data and desired result. I have used temp tables in processes to manipulate data and never used QueryDef to accomplish. Sorry, I am just not following this convoluted process.

Comment: Now you want to save`auswahl`and`Zieladresse` to`tbl_Auswahl`? How are they connected to`some SQL`? Or do you want to create a row in`tbl_Auswahl`for each row of`some SQL`? Last loop will only execute once as`cpRS`cursor is on last inserted element.First`MoveNext`reaches`.EOF

Comment: @ComputerVersteher I am not entirely sure yet how to go about this. I need information from the form for a one-time-use. Afterwards, the data is useless, which is why I don't know if  my thought process makes sense. I want to save the information from the two extra columns in a table that consists of those exact two columns. Because I fill the table in the order that I read the form with, I believe I don't need any further information about the row I got the values from when using the information from the temporary table. When I'm done iterating over every record, I'd delete all rows.

Comment: @ComputerVersteher So the entire process should look like this: Create form like existing form and add two columns. Let user input data into additional columns and save user input somewhere (for example in a temporary table). use user input in vba code. delete entries from temporary table. repeat

Comment: You need`cpRS.MoveFirst`before updating with`otherRS`(after adding a new record the recordset, cursor of`cpRS`points to this record which is last before`cpRS.EOF`), but you shouldn't rely on the sort order. As you allready store the temp values in tbl_auswahl, storing the restricedQuery data to that table too and skipping the ADODB recordset makes your life easier. Don't forget to compress the db (that contains the temp table) regulary if data is deleted!